# MySql recursive procedure: how to fix infinity loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to code stored procedure in MySql to delete whole subtree from tree structure.

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE delete_with_children(IN node INT)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE child_id INT;
            DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE parent_id = node;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

            DELETE from nodes where id = node;
            OPEN cur;
            WHILE(finished < 1) DO
                FETCH cur INTO child_id;
                CALL delete_with_children(child_id);
            END WHILE;
            CLOSE cur;
        END;
```

It insert itself well but when I've tried to execute it with argument 4 for that structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw8D0.jpg , I get such error: Recursive limit 100 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine delete_with_children. I would be grateful if someone help me.

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you don't need a stored procedure. A single query with a recursive CTE will do.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178023/select-all-children-from-infinite-parent-child-relations might help